# Dynamically Updating MySQL Table For Counting Matching Data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In MySQL I have created two tables for my database, to serve data on a React frontend. The tables hold information where animals are categorized in certain groups, and I would like to make the 'count' of the size of the group dynamic when a user adds or removes animals from a group category.
The first table has an auto-incrementing ID for each row, as well as the animal name and which group it is currently in:

| ID (auto-increment) | Animal | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | Domestic |
| 2 | Dog | Domestic |
| 3 | Giraffe | Wild |
| 4 | Lion | Wild |
| 5 | Hyena | Wild |

In a second table, I am keeping track of the number of animals in each group:

| Group | Number in Group |
| --- | --- |
| Domestic | 2 |
| Wild | 3 |

I have tried to do so with a SQL command in a Node.js cloud function

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM first_table
WHERE Group = "Group_name";
```

Where "Group_name" is the specific group, such as domestic or wild. Even though the SQL query runs, it doesn't update the Groups table.

I have tried using triggers in MySQL but it still does not update the table even with hard-coded rows. Any help with triggers or a SQL statement would be awesome!

Comment: Note that group is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier. And we wouldn't normally strore derived data

Comment: "Even though the SQL query runs, it doesn't update....."   Why should a SQL query do an  update?  I think someone invented the [update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) statement for doing such things but as Strawberry said, "we wouldn't normally strore derived data"

Answer (score 0):

Using a view might be a better solution.

```
CREATE VIEW groupcount AS
SELECT 
   `group` as animalgroup, 
   count(*) as groupcount
FROM first_table
GROUP BY `group`;
```

After this you simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM groupcount ;
```

which will give you the results for every `animalgroup`, with count `groupcount`.